# Formatting issues with live clock

Tags: c#, wpf

Trying to format the returned value from a class which updates an application resource when there is a change.

Here is my code:

```
public class NotifyingDateTime : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private DateTime _now;

    public NotifyingDateTime()
    {
        _now = DateTime.Now;
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }
    public string formated
    {
        get 
        { 
            DateTime datenow = Now;
            //Format the datatime
            string format = "dd MMM, yyyy - h:mm:s tt";
            string formatted = datenow.ToString(format);
            return formatted;
        }
    }
    public DateTime Now
    {
        get { return _now; }
        private set
        {
            _now = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Now"));
        }
    }
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Now = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

This is the binding in the Application Resource:

```
{Binding Source={StaticResource NotifyingDateTime}, Path=formated}
```

When the application is first run the formatting works fine, but because i'm referencing `formated` and not `Now` the binding doesn't notice the update, as that takes place in `Now`.

What is the best way to do this? How can I have a Ticker update an Application Resource with the current DateTime formatted to how I want it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you've binded the `formated` property so raising change notification on `Now` will not force binding to update. so raise change notification on `formated` after changing the value and binding may update the same to UI.

change

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Now"));
```

to

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("formated"));
```

Comment: Ooooooh, thanks! I thought that was doing something else! lol

Comment: @MartynBall, when you use a converter on `Now` it is necessary to raise notification on the same. but your approach is to use another property to perform the formatting, so change notification on the binded property is required instead of source property. last but not the least happy coding :)